# Why does Azure's Role Definitions API return more than Permission struct for a role definition?

Tags: azure, go, sdk, azure-rest-api, azure-rbac

I'm using the Azure Go SDK to call the [Role Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-definitions/get) endpoint.

The data that comes back confuses me. I see a `*Permissions` pointer in the response, but it's not by itself. It's in a slice of pointers. How can there be more than one `*Permissions` pointer in the response? After reading [Azure custom roles - Custom role properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles#custom-role-properties), I learned that there are Actions, DataActions, NotActions, and NotDataActions. But, wouldn't you be able to describe all of these within one `Permissions` struct?

I have a test program I used to see this in action too. I noticed that my slice of pointers always had just one pointer. But I did see the expected actions and not actions in it (I was testing the Contributor built-in role for my subscription).

Before running my program, I authenticated my Azure CLI, so that the default credentials would use these credentials and the code would run without error.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/authorization/armauthorization/v2"
)

func main() {
    // Default cred from env vars
    cred, _ := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    client, _ := armauthorization.NewRoleDefinitionsClient(cred, nil)

    // Get the role definition using its roleDefinitionId and its scope.
    roleDefinitionID := "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
    scope := "/subscriptions/<my-subscription>"
    rd, _ := client.Get(context.TODO(), scope, roleDefinitionID, nil)

    lenPerms := len((*rd.RoleDefinition.Properties).Permissions)
    fmt.Printf("length of Permissions = %d\n", lenPerms)
    lenActions := len((*(*rd.RoleDefinition.Properties).Permissions[0]).Actions)
    fmt.Printf("length of Actions in Permissions = %d\n", lenActions)
    lenNotActions := len((*(*rd.RoleDefinition.Properties).Permissions[0]).NotActions)
    fmt.Printf("length of NotActions in Permissions = %d\n", lenNotActions)
}
```

It produced the following output:

```golang
length of Permissions = 1
length of Actions in Permissions = 1
length of NotActions in Permissions = 8
```

While troubleshooting, one theory I had for why there could be a list of `Permissions` structs instead of just one is that maybe each time a new action is added to a role, Azure would store this as a "permission added event" etc, and the API response is showing us all of these events.

I tested this theory by trying this test instead with a custom role that I created. While creating my custom role, I cloned the permissions of the built-in role Contributor. Then I ran my test program. I got 1, 1, 8 (like before with the built-in Contributor role). Then, I added a new NotAction to my custom role and finally I ran my test program again. I got 1, 1, 9 this time. So it still put all the data in the first `Permissions` struct.

For more context, the reason this is important to me is that I'm making software that needs to know which Actions, NotActions, DataActions, and NotDataActions exist on a role definition. And I'm wondering if I need to take into account every `Permissions` struct pointed to by the slice `Properties.Permissions`, or if I can safely assume that the first item in that slice is all the data the program will ever need to take into account.